# why when I rotate a point in a curve all the points is rotating?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I am making something with a curve and everything is good but suddenly when I rotate a point all the points rotate with it. How can I make them rotate separately?
here is before rotation
[image]

and here is after rotation
[image]

Comment: Are you rotating in object mode? Do you have proportional editing disabled? Can you post a screen grab or a blend file?

Comment: @cegaton I am in edit mode,and proportional editing is off

Comment: No pictures or other info to share?

Comment: @cegaton I have added images,as you can see I just rotate 1 point and everything rotated,and also you can see the proportional editing is off and I am in edit mode

Comment: Based on the image it looks like you should add more curve points if you want a tight turn. Blender curves will interpolate curve points.

Comment: Exactly, the actual points are not moving, it is just the interpolated mesh created from those points. Adding another subdivision near the fold would potentially solve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are editing curves, selecting the point of the curve also selects the two control handles that define the curve going into and out of the control point. Rotating this selection moves all three and may not give the result you want.

Another property of the curves control point is Tilt, you can see this value under Transform in the properties sidebar <kbd>N</kbd>. When using a flat extrusion shape this can 'twist' the extrusion sideways without altering the curve shape.

[image]

You need to be cautious with it's use as a large tilt value compared to the next points can give a visible crease.

[image]